# Javascript regex escape

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression like this which extract the content between 2 characters and in this case its between 2 #'s

```
 (?<=\#)(.*?)(?=\#)
```

and um using it as follows

```
var extract = str.match(/(?<=\#)(.*?)(?=\#)/).pop();
```

but the regex gives errors since I think I need to escape it.  How do I  correctly apply escape characters for the above regex?

Comment: Javascript does not support `(?<=)`

Comment: How may I use this in javascript? since regex is kind of universal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex may be overkill for this task.

```
var result = str.split("#")[1] || "";
```

- If there is no `#` in the string, result is the empty string.
- If there is only one `#` in the string, result is everything after it.
- If there are two or more `#` in the string, result is the substring between the first and second `#`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#(.*?)#
```

or

```
#([^#]+)#
```

Simply use this and grab the `group 1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/14

```
var re = /#(.*?)#/gm;
var str = 'bazbarfoo#asad#';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```